# Errors when moving a project from a computer to another

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the AJMRTD project from sourceforge, and tried it on a computer(PC-A) and it went well. But downloading the same project from the same source to another computer (PC-B) went bad, some errors like:

```
Error:(98, 19) error: type PassportService does not take parameters
Error:(98, 70) error: type PassportService does not take parameters
Error:(105, 25) error: BACKeySpec is abstract; cannot be instantiated
Error:(183, 32) error: cannot find symbol method getBiometricTemplates()
Error:(198, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getBiometricTemplates()
```

I tried copying the project from Pc-A to Pc-B, but it lead to the same error.

**Update:**
Now after doing a reset to android studio ( delete the .AndroidStudio existed in the User Folder.
and After taking the SDK folder from PC-A and copying it to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android`
A new error occurred:
Error:(290, 34) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to C
where C is a type-variable:

```
C extends Object declared in class APDUFingerprint
Note: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\ajmrtd\ajmrtd\ajmrtd\scuba_smartcards_j2se\src\main\java\net\sourceforge\scuba\smartcards\APDUFingerprint.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':scuba_smartcards_j2se:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**Update 2:**

```
private boolean isAllowedBy(APDUFingerprint<C,R> thisPrint, APDUFingerprint otherPrint) {
        for (C c: thisPrint.commandResponsePairs.keySet()) {
            C otherC = getSimilarCommandAPDU(c, otherPrint); // **the error imply to getSimilar**
            if (otherC == null) { continue; }
            if (!isAllowedBy(c, otherC)) { return false; }
            int response = thisPrint.getResponse(c);
            int otherResponse = otherPrint.getResponse(otherC);
            if (response == -1 || otherResponse == -1) { continue; }
            if (response != otherResponse) { return false; }
        }
        System.out.println("DEBUG: isAllowedBy(" + thisPrint + ", " + otherPrint + ")");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I would be nice if you provided some code that you are looking at and doesn't compile.

Comment: @cricket_007 the code is available here: https://sourceforge.net/p/ajmrtd/code/HEAD/tree/
The error shown is in APDUfingerprint class. ( see my update again) and it does not imply to any specific **fatal error **

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. Enter : `C:\Users\yourusername` and then move the folder `.AndroidStudio1.5` to any other path ( desktop maybe), then open Android Studio. 
Now Android studio will start as if it is the first time launched on this computer . Then try to open the project with the error, if the same error occur , restore the `.AndroidStudio1.5` to `C:\Users\yourusername` . et Voila!